# WPAlchemy - Checkboxes not saving

Tags: wpalchemy

I'm using have_fields to loop through an array and create a list of checkboxes. Everything seems to be working great, except that the checkboxes aren't consistently showing as "checked" on the backend. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php $items = array(
        'bio', 
        'youtube',
        'articles', 
        'learn-more', 
        'testimonials', 
        'twitter',
        'custom',
    ); ?>

    <p>
    <?php while ($mb->have_fields('t_enabled_widgets', count($items))): ?>

        <?php $item = $items[$mb->get_the_index()]; ?>

        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $item; ?>"<?php $mb->the_checkbox_state($item); ?>/> <?php echo ucwords(str_replace("-", " ", $item )); ?><br/>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </p>
```

For example, when I check the first 4 boxes, (Bio, Youtube, Articles, and Learn More), all is well. When I check the 5th, it *saves* to the database, but when the page reloads, it's unchecked. This is obviously a problem because when you then "Update" the page *again* it's submitted as a blank value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching I decided to try one of the alternative methods listed in the checkbox-meta.php example file. I used a "foreach" loop instead of the "while" loop and the checkbox state is now loading properly.

Here's the updated code:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $i => $item): ?>

    <?php $mb->the_field('t_enabled_widgets', WPALCHEMY_FIELD_HINT_CHECKBOX_MULTI); ?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $item; ?>"<?php $mb->the_checkbox_state($item); ?>/>
    <span><?php echo ucwords(str_replace("-", " ", $item )); ?></span>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```